# New object belonging_to won't associate with Devise User who created it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When my user creates an object that should have his `id` on it, the `id` comes out `nil`. Ideas why?

```
# controllers/units_controller.rb

class UnitsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @unit = Unit.new
    @unit.user = current_user  # also tried .user_id = current_user.id
[...]


# models/unit.rb

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # :user has_many :units too
[...]
```

The object is saved successfully, but with an empty `user_id` field (showing `nil`). 
No exception is thrown. There is no callback on save.

Comment: need more info.  Is there an exception thrown or is it just not saved?  If the latter, maybe the unit doesn't have a `user_id`?  Are there any callbacks around Unit's save?  Does `@unit` save successfully?  Do you `save` `@unit` after the code shown?

Comment: Have you tried `current_user.build_unit` or `current_user.create_unit`? Is that the entirety of your #new action? What does your #create action look like? If you're doing this in the standard Rails two step (#new (POST)-> #create), then you need to associate Unit with current_user in the #create action as well.

Comment: @andrewle: As the "[...]" indicate, this is not the entirety of `#new`. However you made me realize that the `@unit.user` allocation should rather go in the `Unit#create` method, which solved the problem. Can you make an answer out of that so people who get the same problem see the answer?

Comment: @jonallard: Just added it as an answer. Glad to have pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this in the standard Rails two step (#new (POST)-> #create), then you need to associate Unit with current_user in the #create action.

```
def create
  @unit = Unit.new
  @unit.user = current_user
  # ...
end
```